# Why I am unable to select Value in Object inside an Array using Property Name, that the .getOwnPropertyNames() finds, after reading from csv file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

### Problem

I'm having a problem selecting the `Value` in an Object that is inside an `Array` with Properties that can be found using both `.getOwnPropertyName()` and `Object.keys()`

However, I am receiving **`undefined`** instead of the value. I have since worked around it but it boggles my mind and I'd like to understand why this happens.

Since I was unable to find an answer for the problem anywhere, I hope that this question also helps anyone else facing this issue

### Stack:

- Env: Node.js, `npm`
- Modules: `fs`, `csv-parser`

### Description

- I load data from CSV file using readable stream with `csv-parser` and receive array of objects.
- I then want to select the value in the object (single key-value pair) to substitute value in another object.

  - But it doesn't really matter since the issue is observable right after assigning that array to a variable name and even inside the promise.
- I tried storing that key name in another variable:

  - Using both single-quotes / double quotes
  - Using literal with single quotes (`"'keyname'"`)
  - Using dot selector, using table selector, and nothing would work.
- I then tried to console.log some:

  - Object.keys() and my_object.getOwnPropertyNames() both return that exact keyname
  - logging the `my_array` returns array of objects
  - logging the `my_array[0]` returns single object
  - `typeof(my_object)` returns object
  - `typeof(my_array)` returns object but `console.dir(my_array)` returns `Array (1000) [Object, Object, Object, ...]`
  - `console.dir(my_array[0])` is `Object {user: "D0568824B5F1D96E"}`

**BUT**

- `my_object.hasOwnProperty(my_key)` returns `false`
- So I ultimately solved it by selecting with

```js
my_array[0][(Object.keys(my_array[0]))[0]]
```

- But this looks really unclean and needless... I thought it could be related to csv file encoding but it's `UTF-8` upon checking.
- I also tried changing the property name.
- Also, the same exact code was able to create array with readable objects. The difference between the files is that the non-working csv has single property objects while the other has multiple properties objects.
- Could this be the problem? The csv data is a list of hex user IDs.

### Code:

```
const parseCSV = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

let array = [];

const readFromCSV = async (sourceFile) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fs.createReadStream(sourceFile)
        .pipe(parseCSV())
        .on('data', row => {
            array.push(row);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('Data ingested'); //console.log of array[0].keyname results in the issue at this point but also outside the function, after resolving the promise and assigning it to a variable name
            resolve(array);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: `.pipe(parseCSV())` This looks a bit suspect. Should `parseCSV` *really* be called before `.pipe`?

Comment: Can you add result of console.dir of the example object?

Comment: The result of console.dir for a single object looks like this: ```Object {user: "D0568824B5F1D96E"}``` I also added it to the question.

The ```.pipe(parseCSV())``` looks ok to me as far as I can tell and also according to the module docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser

Comment: Are you sure `typeof(my_array)` returns Array??

Comment: Checked it again and it actually returns object (fixed it in the question). My confusion, probably because `console.dir(my_array)` returns `Array (1000) [Object, Object, Object, ...]`. I just now tried mapping it onto new variable but that new variable has the same issue.

Comment: Please post the example data that doesn't work as well how you call `readFromCSV` and try to access the result.

Comment: If the property name looks right but still doesn't work, check for invisible characters.